# Multiple 'createTag' error on Tag-It jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tag-it

I am using the tag-it jquery plugin from https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

```
var ip_elem = $('#my-tags');

ip_elem.tagit({
    removeConfirmation: false,
    caseSensitive: false,
    allowDuplicates: false,
    allowSpaces: true,
    readOnly: false,
    tagLimit: null,
    singleField: false,
    singleFieldDelimiter: ',',
    singleFieldNode: null,
    tabIndex: null,
    placeholderText:"Enter Tags"
});
```

Now, I want to programmatically add more tags using the `createTag` method.

```
var newTags = ["javascript","php","ruby","python"];

for(var k=0;k<newTags.length;k++){
    ip_elem.tagit("createTag", newTags[k]);
}
```

It displays the first tag in the input, but for the second tag says : `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tagit prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'createTag'`. It stops and doesn't add any more tags in the input box now. So, in the end, only the first tag is formed (which in this case would be `javascript`)

What is going wrong here?

Comment: because everytime your are initializing `tagit` to `ip_elem` in loop..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : That's how they show it in the documentation. Could you take a look please? : https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#createtagtaglabel-additionalclass

Comment: You see there they have shown for only single tag, not multiple.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Yeah. I see that. So, how do you suggest I add all the tags from my array?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: I think the `tagit` automatically detects if it had been previously initialized.

Comment: Aha!! I don't think so.. you might need to make use of `availableTags` option here.,

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : `availableTags` gets the tags currently in the input box. I am trying to set new tags.

Comment: Yea.. What I was saying was initially set your availableTags to some array and then update the array and again assign it..

Answer (score 1):

**Take a look at this example i've created in Fiddle:**

In the Fiddle example, it will dynamically create the `tags` `onload` and if you try and enter a `tag` with the same name, it won't let you add it.

Hope this will help you out, it's got events to show you what actually happening on the page.

```
var newTags = ["javascript","php","ruby","python"];

var addEvent = function(text) {
    $('#events_container').append(text + '<br>');
};

$(function(){
    var ip_elem = $('#myTags');

    ip_elem.tagit({
        removeConfirmation: false,
        caseSensitive: false,
        allowDuplicates: false,
        allowSpaces: true,
        readOnly: false,
        tagLimit: null,
        singleField: false,
        singleFieldDelimiter: ',',
        singleFieldNode: null,
        tabIndex: null,
        placeholderText:"Enter Tags"
    });

    ip_elem.tagit({
        availableTags: newTags,
        beforeTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
            if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                addEvent('Before Tag Added: ' + ip_elem.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
            }
        },
        afterTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {
            if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
                addEvent('After Tag Added: ' + ip_elem.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
            }
        },
        beforeTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('Before Tag Removed: ' + ip_elem.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        },
        afterTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('After Tag Removed: ' + ip_elem.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        },
        onTagClicked: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('On Tag Clicked: ' + ip_elem.tagit('tagLabel', ui.tag));
        },
        onTagExists: function(evt, ui) {
            addEvent('On Tag Exists: ' + ip_elem.tagit('tagLabel', ui.existingTag));
        }
    });   

    for(var k=0;k<newTags.length;k++)
    {
        ip_elem.tagit("createTag", newTags[k]);
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zrcn2wn/5/)